# Tp entity to the middle of a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to teleport an armor stand to the player but it must stand perfectly in the middle of the block. If the player is standing only on half of the block the armor stand should be teleported to the middle of the block.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the type of situation that `/execute align` was made for:

```
/execute at @p align xyz run tp @e[type=armor_stand] ~.5 ~ ~.5
```